# Web Site Redirecting Twice

Tags: c#, http, redirect

I am trying to login a website with c# , I succedd to login with sending username and password, I also opened auto redirecting property of request but web server needs 2 redirection in order to enter welcome page but in my code it can only redirects once. How can I get final directed page? Any help would be appreciated.

```
HttpWebRequest request =(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://website.com/client/patronlogin.loginpageform/DEFAULT");
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;  // IMPORTANT

        request.Method = "POST";
        int pass = sfsdf1;
        int no = dsfsdfdf0;

        String formContent = "t%3Aac=%24002f%24002ftreblead.com%24002fclient%24002fdefault%24002fsearch%24002faccount%24003f&t%3Aformdata=H4sIAAAAAAAAAJWQv0oDQRDGx4NAMJ1gEURstN2zMI02BkEQDgkc1mFvb7xs2Ntdd%2FZMbKx8CRufQKz0CVLY%2BQ4%2BgI2FlYV7J6Lg%2F274mJnv932XD9CarMAyIXdiFA%2B4d0YnppB6czysCJ3mJZKDnnEF45aLETLPLZJ3Jz0mjEMlM5ZxQtbPgsiF35Wo8tUUfWXXDmad%2B8Xb5wjmEugIo8N3tR8%2BelhIxvyYx4rrIk69k7rYmloP8%2B%2Buf8Hq%2Fxdr4IxAorTKSkkkjZ5d5RuHTxd3EcDUfmtpOdHEuJyO4BSgwXyTfr2pT1qTJeh%2BsUU1hw9Btn8MIkxpjUbtiTXk%2FnOO8%2FSxe3N9thNBlEBbKBm29xrvunpUWAahrr6R6qrbr%2BbD9Q%2FjCx9ggTUPAgAA&j_username="+no.ToString()+"&j_password="+pass.ToString();

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formContent);
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
        // Get the response ...
        WebResponse response;
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

        richTextBox1.AppendText(reader.ReadToEnd());
        richTextBox1.AppendText(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(reader.ReadToEnd()));


        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
```

Comment: Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.maximumautomaticredirections.aspx

Comment: It did not worked, not redirecting twice.

Comment: Is the 2nd redirect through HTTP 201 or its a Javascript or a <Meta HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" /> thing ?

Comment: Both redirects are through HTTP 200.

Comment: 200 is an OK message which means you have reached the landing page. Redirection HTTP 1.1 Code starts with 3

Comment: But after 200 HTTP there is an another 200 HTTP if it is OK why I get another 200 HTTP I observed it with fiddler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that you need to set **MaximumAutomaticRedirections** property to a higher value?